# How can I show tweets on a map in Processing?

Tags: twitter, dictionary, processing

I have been trying to use a map to show locations of tweets (from Streaming API) in Processing. But I haven't found any good resource/tutorial. Will anyone help me please?

Comment: Please see my answer to your other question. And in the future, please edit your original question (and/or topic) rather than posting duplicate questions.

Comment: Also, if you try to give more elaborate questions that show research, links, source code, etc. people will be more likely to help you. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

The best library for maps in Processing currently is [Unfolding](http://unfoldingmaps.org/). You will find tutorials on their site.

Answer (score 0):

Jer Thorp has done a fair bit of this... he has several tutorials and source code links on his site: http://blog.blprnt.com/source-code-tutorial

Comment: @Fari was this (or any other) answer useful ? Please consider upvoting one or more, and accepting one...

Answer (score 0):

you might be interested in checking out my work on tweetedtrips.com.

This uses the streaming api to pull tweets, geocode those which don't already have location information attached to them and plot them on a Google Map.

Peter